# CSS and JS folders don't exists in public folder in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I've just installed Laravel 6.0.2. I then created authentication using the following command.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
```

Now, I run the login page and it displays like the following.

[image]

Now I'm setting up the `Layouts.php` files.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

I tried this one as well.

```
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Before Laravel 6 the folder of CSS and JS exists in public folder, but now I can't find that folder. Can anyone tell me `{{ asset('css/app.css') }}` what is the location of this `asset` in Laravel 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command to implement Auth is as follows:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

If your Login and Register page only shows plain HTML. And CSS is not loading properly then run this two command:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer Thanks, I read the document about laravel mix https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#installation over here, is there any way to without installing node modules?